# Is it possible to skip IndexRebuilder in the startup process of mongodb 2.6?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

There are more than 10k databases and 100k collections( with indexes) in our Replica Set, and mongod intance startup progress is a very long time job, more than 30 minutes.

And I have set noIndexBuildRetry, and there were lots of logs:

```
2015-06-06T17:53:45.818+0800 [IndexRebuilder] opening db:  database_000001a
2015-06-06T17:53:45.925+0800 [IndexRebuilder] opening db:  database_000002b
....
2015-06-06T18:33:47.769+0800 [IndexRebuilder] opening db:  database_....
```

Is it possible to skip IndexRebuilder in the startup process of mongodb 2.6  ?

Any reply will be appreciated.